# How can I use mod_rewrite to do this

Tags: mod-rewrite

I would like to take a url at my site:

http://mysite.com/jk/drawing

but operationally drop the "jk" dir and have my users see this:

http://mysite.com/drawing

Is this possible? If so can someone give me an example of how it is done?

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is go and change all of your links from looking like this: `http://mysite.com/jk/drawing` to looking like this: `http://mysite.com/drawing`. Without doing this, people will still see all the `/jk/` URLs everywhere, the only thing you can do about it is to make sure you've changed all your links. Then add these rules to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} mysite.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/jk/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /jk/$1 [L]
```

In order to correct for all the links still pointing to `/jk/` that you don't have any control over:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} mysite.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /jk/([^\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]
```